# Trying to extract the last number on a line, with sets of numbers delimited by spaces

Tags: regex, perl

So I've extracted the digits from a log file and it looks like this:

```
2011 04 13 23 54 14 601 04 13 23 54 14 10 35 1 14 8080 59 250
```

What I'm trying to get is the last number (250), and it will loop through each line of the log.  Once I get the last number from each line, I will do some calculations...I just can't extract that last number at the end of the line.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is an array, `@digits`, then the last one is `$digits[-1]`.
If your data is in a string, use the `split` to get it into an array.

Answer (score 7):

```
while (<>) {
    my ($last) = /(\d+)$/;
}
```

Comment: The regex approach can be faster for large strings.